# Sum a group of products using SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a question I have tried function SUM and SUMIFS, It doesn't seem to work for me I am not sure what I missed in the formula.

[image]

Here, I want to sum a group of product in column B which match the specific date in column D.
I tried

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,{"1","4","6"},$A:$A,$D1))
```

the result turned to be 12, but the correct result should be 16. If I separated it into three function >

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"1",$A:$A,$D1)+SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"4",$A:$A,$D1)+SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"6",$A:$A,$D1)
```

It works fine. but I just want to know if I can actually group it or make it shorter because I have a lot of product to be grouped.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

For some reason that I can't figure out, I was not able to get it to work using `ARRAYFORMULA` and `SUMIFS`.

But this formula with nested `IF` works fine and also takes care of additional products in E.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((IF(SPLIT($G2, ",")=$B:$B, IF($A:$A=$F2, $C:$C, 0), 0))))`

[image]

Comment: I will try to figure out with your formula. It seems work there. Appreciate for your help Broly! :)